# Curve fitting on grouped data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, curve-fitting, stat

I desperately need to solve a problem using python which I have recently started learning.

I have a small trended dataset (1500 Rows and ~30 columns). I need to do a polynomial curve fitting on this data set and export the new dataset as a CSV. So this data is grouped by 2 columns ie. product and risk and interval is the time from 1-60. I am able to do the curve fitting for 1 group and 1 column at a time, but unable to figure out how to scale this up so that I can perform the same thing for all the other columns and all the groups. Also I

I have used the following code for this analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline

df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ashish1104/Desktop/Book1.csv')
df.columns=[x.lower()for x in df.columns]
df.head()

dfg=df.groupby(['product','risk'])

for name, group in dfg:
        x=dfg.get_group(name)['interval']
        y=dfg.get_group(name)['adb']
        z = np.polyfit(x, y, 6)
        f = np.poly1d(z)
        y_new = f(x)
        print (y_new)
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

[Link to dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BZBYCWhhVSOGJ5YV9QMXFIcGc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide all relevant code/data in an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: it's not really clear what you're asking... do you get an error when you run your code?

Comment: When I tried to download the data, google told me to log in and then ask permission to access the file.

Comment: @JamesPhillips My apologies, I have updated the link, you should be able to read the file. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @maxymoo I need help in scaling this code so that python can perform curve fitting on all the columns across all the groups (group is a combination of Product and Risk here). The code that I posted here iterates through all the groups and saves the output to z and f, but it also seems like values from the previous iterations get overwritten, additionally I don't see that the group name and column 'interval' is being saved in the variables z and f. Secondly, I need help in performing this operation on all the columns of the database.

Comment: I was able to download the data, thank you.  I understand the problem better after having reviewed the CSV file.  I'm looking into this now.

Comment: I'm too unfamiliar with pandas to make any headway on this, my apologies.

Comment: @JamesPhillips np, Thanks for trying .